# Does anyone know how this inner product space question has been solved?

Tags: inner-products

[Here is the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRvod.png)
If anyone can explain to me, that'll be great!

Also, is [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdYdc.png) an inner space? For me, it comes out not to be. At the step 
(u+v,w), it gets disproved.

Comment: You need to format this using \LaTeX.  As posed, I can't make heads or tails of what you are asking.  The two links do not seem related.

Comment: And post your disproof.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, integration by parts is your friend :

$$\int_0^\pi (x+1) \cos(x) dx = \int_0^\pi x \cos(x) dx  + \underbrace{\int_0^\pi \cos(x) dx}_{=0} $$

$$=  [ - x \sin(x) ]_0^\pi - \int_0^\pi -\sin(x) dx = 0 - [-\cos(x)]_0^\pi = 1-(-1) = 2 $$

For your second question, it's unrelated to the first, but it's clearly an inner product space (forget about the matrix writting, it's the same as the usual $\Bbb{R}^4$ space)